# SceneKit collada animation

Tags: animation, time, scenekit, collada, caanimation

I created scene and added few nodes from different *.dae files. These nodes has animations. I want to play animations for nodes independently. For example, node1 will run animation from 10th frame to 20th frame, but node2 will run animation from 30th frame to 50th frame. If i use SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyPlayUsingSceneTimeBase key and i set sceneTime value then the animations of both nodes is playing synchronously.

If i use SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyPlay key i must first stop all animation for all nodes and for all them child nodes. Then i must start all animation for all nodes and for all them child nodes with required timeOffset value. Then animation is playing, but it does not look correct

Help me please!

Comment: I think the property you want to set is "beginTime" and not "timeOffset". Use a beginTime of (CACurrentMediaTime()+<some value> or just <some value> if you are "scene time" based.